# How to create a voting for proposal contract using ERC20Votes from OpenZeppelin?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, erc20

I have found [ERC20Votes](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol) extension to `ERC20` contract and decided to use it for creating simple voting for proposal contract.
In Dev comments it is said that this extension keeps a history of each account's vote power. In my voting contract I store the block number in which proposal was created and query `votingPower` for this block in my `vote` function.
The question is: how can I prevent single address from double voting?
And are there any contracts beside `ERC20Votes` which I can use for building my own voting for proposals contract?

I have tried using `mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => bool))` to track which accounts have already voted for proposal. But I expect to find a better solution.
I have almost finished building voting contract using only `ERC20Votes`, but I think that there should be a better way to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you should store `mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => bool))` to track which accounts have already voted
2. Consider using [Governor](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/governance/Governor.sol) and related contracts. You should only override some methods in order to implement required business logic. Most of the stuff is already implemented inside it